# Excel SUMIFS Statement - Calculate profit for each month across multiple years

Tags: excel

I've got three columns of data.

- Sell Date - **Column G** - Contains the day, month and year in dd/mm/yyy format.
- Month (calculated from sell date) - **Column I** - Contains month number
- Profit - **Column M** - Profit in Dollars.

I am trying to calculate the profit made in each month and year.

Current formula using SUMIFS. I look at the data in Column I and if this contains a 1, and if G contains the year 2016 then it's January 2016. Think it's the year function that I don't quite get.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(M9:M50, I9:I50, {"1"}, G9:G50, YEAR=2016))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another column that shows just the year year(G2) or you can use this formula

```
=SUMIFS(M9:M50,G9:G50,">=1/1/2016",G9:G50,"<1/2/2016")
```

I also like this formula that allows you to reference the date in one cell and calculate a 1 month range.  Put 01/01/2016 in cell A1 and the formula does the rest.

```
=SUMIFS(M9:M50,G9:G50,">="&A1,G9:G50,"<" & EDATE(A1,1))
```

Comment: thanks, but that formula is counting all values from M9:M50 and doesnt seem to take into account if month=1

Comment: It uses column G to sleect everything with a January 2016 date.  It will only work if coumn G contains valid dates.  It doen't need to check the month column.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the ranges to match yours and I changed a G range to M by mistake.  It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The `SUMIFS` function doesn't like it when you alter the value of the `IF` parameters. It would be better to use a `SUMPRODUCT` formula to calculate this, for example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((M9:M50)*(I9:I50=1)*(YEAR(G9:G50)=2016))
```

Where:

- `(M9:M50)` are the values you wish to `SUM`.
- `(I9:I50)` are the month values and `1` is the month you wish to specify.
- `(G9:G50)` are the date values you wish to obtain the year from and `2016` is the year you are specifying.

Comment: thanks although the formula has an error. I will try on Windows Excel, im using a MAC.

Comment: Strange, well I've tested it in Windows Excel and it seems to work fine!

Comment: same problem for how odd.